# Dual Monitors & Opening Dialogs

Tags: windows, mfc, modal-dialog

How does one go about making a dialog appear on the same monitor as it's parent window?

If I move my app to the secondary monitor and perform some action which opens a dialog, the dialog will always appear on the primary monitor.  Seems kinda backwards that dialogs do not appear near their parent windows.

Any clues out there?

Comment: If you parent the dialog correctly and/or include a `CenterWindow()` call in the dialog's `OnInitDialog()` it ought to work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, drove me in the right direction to resolve some very old code which pushed dialogs onto the primary display.